# VBA, alternative code for this "x = Array()"

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

`Dim x As Variant
 Dim b As Variant
 x = Array()
 b = x`

my point here is I want to transfer an array with ubound(-1). but it throws error when I'm passing x to b. Can you help explain how I can sort this? is this code "x = Array()" correct?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/0a60a047-6026-49ca-8858-d3d8ac6cc8c8/problems-with-the-vba-array-function-after-windows-august-update?forum=accessdev) MSDN page the cause of the error lies with the August 2019 Windows updates.  There is a link to the Update Catalog if you scroll down the page and KBs are listed for various Windows versions.  I've applied the fix for Win7 x64 and ...=Array() thankfully works again as before.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how are you creating the empty array. Is this what you are trying?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim x As Variant
    Dim b As Variant
    Dim MyArray() As String

    MyArray = Split("")

    x = MyArray()
    b = x

    Debug.Print LBound(MyArray)
    Debug.Print UBound(MyArray)
    Debug.Print "-------"
    Debug.Print LBound(x)
    Debug.Print UBound(x)
    Debug.Print "-------"
    Debug.Print LBound(b)
    Debug.Print UBound(b)
End Sub
```

**Output**

```
0 
-1 
-------
0 
-1 
-------
0 
-1
```

Comment: Hi, someone said to me the cause of it is the windows update. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: Not that I am aware of but I hope you got an answer to your query?